# downloading pdf files with playwright

Tags: python, automation, download, playwright-python

when I try to download a pdf using playwright, the programm open the pdf instead. In Selenium I used to change some settings in the browsers.
this is the script

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\ayoub\Desktop", #Change default directory for downloads
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": False,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome
})
```

I want to do the same in playwright or if there is a better solution I want to know it.

and thanks for your help.

Comment: the problem is the download doesn't start, it open the pdf only. i want a script that force the download

Comment: in chromium the download doesn't start and I don't want to change the settings manually

Comment: oh it worked when i change the browser from chromium to firefox